# Facebook login issue, going to facebook home after permissions

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm using the following code to authorize the application and then ask for permission because could not find a simple way to authorize it simply after logging in. But then the user gets directed to their homepage instead of the application homepage. Was wondering where am I going wrong with it.

```
<fb:if-is-app-user>
   <fb:else>
   <fb:redirect url="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx81&req_perms=publish_stream&canvas="http://apps.facebook.com/felinetest""/>
  </fb:else>
</fb:if-is-app-user>
```

p.s I ask for streaming permissions too in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra quote in after canvas= might be the problem; that is making the snipped invalid XML. You might try just eliminating the quotes around the canvas value and seeing if that works.

As an aside, you should probably edit your question to remove or obfuscate your API key, since I believe those are meant to be kept private.

Comment: Sadly still redirecting to facebook.com